# Can the IMAP MODSEQ SEARCH extension be used with arbitrary metadata tags?

Tags: imap

As I was reading over [rfc4551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551), I noticed that the comment after example 15 in [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551#section-3.4) ("MODSEQ Search Criterion in SEARCH") seems to be wrong.

> Example 15:
>
> ```
>  C: a SEARCH MODSEQ "/flags/\\draft" all 620162338
>  S: * SEARCH 2 5 6 7 11 12 18 19 20 23 (MODSEQ 917162500)
>  S: a OK Search complete
> ```
>
> In the above example, the message numbers of any messages
> containing the string "IMAP4" in the "value" attribute of the
> "/comment" entry and having a mod-sequence equal to or greater
> than 620162338 for the "\Draft" flag are returned in the search
> results.

The `SEARCH` command does not appear to search "/comment" at all.

Does the comment imply that the `MODSEQ` search criteria allows searching for arbitrary metadata changes?

Normally a full METADATA "comment" tag would be either `/private/comment` or `/shared/comment`, but seeing as how `MODSEQ` seems to be designed such that you specify private vs shared via the `entry-type-req` parameter, I wonder if the idea is that the `/private` or `/shared` prefix should be stripped in favor of the `entry-type-req` parameter, thus leaving you with an `entry-name` of `/comment` (which would at least seem to match the intended example based on the explanation below it).

What confuses me is that based on the definition in section 3.4:

```
Syntax:  MODSEQ [<entry-name> <entry-type-req>] <mod-sequence-valzer>

      Messages that have modification values that are equal to or
      greater than <mod-sequence-valzer>.  This allows a client, for
      example, to find out which messages contain metadata items that
      have changed since the last time it updated its disconnected
      cache.  The client may also specify <entry-name> (name of metadata
      item) and <entry-type-req> (type of metadata item) before
      <mod-sequence-valzer>.  <entry-type-req> can be one of "shared",
      "priv" (private), or "all".  The latter means that the server
      should use the biggest value among "priv" and "shared" mod-
      sequences for the metadata item.  If the server doesn't store
      internally separate mod-sequences for different metadata items, it
      MUST ignore <entry-name> and <entry-type-req>.  Otherwise, the
      server should use them to narrow down the search.

      For a flag <flagname>, the corresponding <entry-name> has a form
      "/flags/<flagname>" as defined in [IMAPABNF].  Note that the
      leading "\" character that denotes a system flag has to be escaped
      as per Section 4.3 of [IMAP4], as the <entry-name> uses syntax for
      quoted strings.
```

It seems to confirm my suspicions about being able to use arbitrary metadata tags, but when I read the actual ABNF grammar, I see:

```
   search-modsequence  = "MODSEQ" [search-modseq-ext] SP
                         mod-sequence-valzer

   search-modseq-ext   = SP entry-name SP entry-type-req

   resp-text-code      =/ "HIGHESTMODSEQ" SP mod-sequence-value /
                          "NOMODSEQ" /
                          "MODIFIED" SP set

   entry-name          = entry-flag-name

   entry-flag-name     = DQUOTE "/flags/" attr-flag DQUOTE
                          ;; each system or user defined flag <flag>
                          ;; is mapped to "/flags/<flag>".
                          ;;
                          ;; <entry-flag-name> follows the escape rules
                          ;; used by "quoted" string as described in
                          ;; Section 4.3 of [IMAP4], e.g., for the flag
                          ;; \Seen the corresponding <entry-name> is
                          ;; "/flags/\\seen", and for the flag
                          ;; $MDNSent, the corresponding <entry-name>
                          ;; is "/flags/$mdnsent".

   entry-type-resp     = "priv" / "shared"
                          ;; metadata item type

   entry-type-req      = entry-type-resp / "all"
                          ;; perform SEARCH operation on private
                          ;; metadata item, shared metadata item or both
```

The ABNF grammar appears to limit the metadata explicitly to `/flags/<flagname>`.

I've emailed the authors of this RFC, but the email address of 1 of the 2 authors has already returned to me as a dead end.

I figured that others might also have this question about the above wording in the RFC, that it might be worth posting here to StackOverflow.

If/when I hear back from the only remaining author that may have received my message, I'll post it in the answer section.

In the meantime, perhaps a native IMAP expert on StackOverflow has some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexey Melnikov is the most important author, and he should be reachable at the same address still. He's slow to reply sometimes (he gets a mountain of mail), but ultimately does reply.

As far as I know, none of the document's authors or reviewers had yet implemented the `entry-name/entry-type-req` stuff, or even planned to implement it, so it's quite understandable if something was missed in that area. (I reviewed it, but I think this particular example hadn't been added yet when I did.)

I suggest treating modseq as if it only applies per message, nothing more finely tuned, and implementing CONDSTORE only as described in [RFC 7162](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7162), not in either of the earlier documents. The example [is correct in 7162](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7162#section-3.1.6).

4551 (and later 7162) limit the metadata to `/flags/…` because no other metadata exist in the protocol. It's expected that if another RFC adds metadata, it will also extend `entry-flag-name` and refer to 7162. I don't think anyone has done that. An update to either [RFC 5257](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5257) or [5464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5464) might, but those extensions haven't met a lot of interest and are unlikely ever to be updated. Work in that general direction is more likely be based on [JMAP](https://jmap.io/).

Comment: Thanks @arnt, I expected you might have some knowledge about this :-)

Comment: FWIW, this is exactly what Alexey said happened.